# SVG polygon shape from latLngs

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, latitude-longitude, geography

I am trying to write a `Javascript` function which will allow me to enter any set of bounds and get back a shape of that area (for example provide the bounds of Kansas and get back its shape). I already have the bounds and know that I can create an `svg polygon` and set its `points` attribute to the bounds array (converted to a string). I also understand that since the `points` are really `latLngs` I should set the `viewBox` attr to the bounds of the entire world (so that I can truly enter in any set of coordinates). What I am having trouble understand is how I can effectively "zoom in" so that I can actually see the shape. With the function below I am successfully getting it to render but it is incredibly small and I am unsure of how to have it fit as much of the box as possible? I began looking at D3 but then wasn't sure that was the best solution as I am not trying to put these on a map, I am just trying to draw them.

```
var pointsData = function(bounds) ->
 points = []
 i = 0
 while i < bounds.length
   points.push bounds[i].lat + ' ' + bounds[i].lng
   i++
 return points.toString().replace(",", "");;
```

and then setting the `points` attr of a given `svg` to the result of the `pointsData` function.

---

**EDIT > Solution:**

Ended up using HTML5 Canvas and map projector function:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtjgwa45/1/

Comment: Find x1: the smallest x value, y1: smallest y value, x2: largest x value, y2: largest y value among your projected points. Then, set the viewbox="x1 y1 x2 y2".

Comment: Note: as you seems open to d3, you must know that D3 geographic stuff is handled by *topojson*, both a D3js plugin (topojson.js) and a smart geojson format (.topojson files). Google is your friend: topojson api. Check out bl.ocksplorer.org

Comment: Yes but most resources talk about it in terms of on a map. I know how to draw it on a map but I am trying to just in a normal div. I've decided to use a canvas element and a map projector function, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Please share back your solution (jsfiddle demo or link). As we (contributors) take on our time to help we appreciate in return to learn from the final solution, and to pool it together here.

Comment: Yes I was just doing that! Give me a second. It was written for angular so I'm converting it to a basic enough js example